# Is it safe to put a radiator pipe through a load-bearing brick wall?

Tags: plumbing, radiator

I am getting a new radiator installed to replace an old ones. The pipes came from room next door and existing pipes were unsightly, partly because they came through bottom of joist/floor/bottom of skirting.

I asked installer to install new pipes directly through wall to then be used with corner valves to give neat finish with pipes not really visible.

But installer said not safe to install through solid wall. Is he correct and if so can it be done safely, by casing the pipe as it goes through within something else?

Comment: What did he say was the problem with installing them through the 'solid' wall.  Pictures would be good.  What does solid wall mean?

Comment: I mean load bearing brick wall, two bricks thick no cavity. I think he meant there was a risk of the brick moving and compressing the pipe.

Comment: It would be OK  and safe as long as you used sleeves to protect the pipes running through the wall.

Comment: I understand the principle but what do 'sleeves' look like, is that what I would ask for at a plumbers merchants.

Comment: There's no way a small hole bored through a brick wall is going to collapse. At worst, a single brick or part of a brick might settle, but even that's unlikely. This is not a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why the location through the wall cannot be changed to bring the feed water to the radiator.  A good sleeve for this situation would probable be two pipe sized larger of Sch 40 iron pipe.